# Access Error: The ORDER BY expression includes fields that are not selected by the query

Tags: ms-access

I keep getting the same error: But as far as I can tell it is included in the Query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 tblOutlets.OutletName, tblOutlets.Parish, Count([Query OOSActions].OODate) AS CountOfOODate1
FROM tblOutlets INNER JOIN [Query OOSActions] ON tblOutlets.OutletID = [Query OOSActions].OutletLookup
WHERE ((([Query OOSActions].OODate) Between [Forms]![Settings]![StartDate] And [Forms]![Settings]![EndDate]) AND (([Query OOSActions].Classification)="Biscuit"))
GROUP BY tblOutlets.OutletName, tblOutlets.Parish
HAVING (((tblOutlets.Parish)="St. Mary"))
ORDER BY Count([Query OOSActions].OODate) DESC;

UNION

SELECT TOP 1 tblOutlets.OutletName, tblOutlets.Parish, Count([Query OOSActions].OODate) AS CountOfOODate1
FROM tblOutlets INNER JOIN [Query OOSActions] ON tblOutlets.OutletID = [Query OOSActions].OutletLookup
WHERE ((([Query OOSActions].OODate) Between [Forms]![Settings]![StartDate] And [Forms]![Settings]![EndDate]) AND (([Query OOSActions].Classification)="Biscuit"))
GROUP BY tblOutlets.OutletName, tblOutlets.Parish
HAVING (((tblOutlets.Parish)="St. Catherine"))
ORDER BY Count([Query OOSActions].OODate) DESC;
```

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with MSAccess but having a `;` before a UNION looks wrong. _(Having an ORDER BY before UNION looks wrong too.)_

Comment: I removed them. Same problem

Comment: Change `ORDER BY Count([Query OOSActions].OODate) DESC` to `ORDER BY CountOfOODate1` -- it requires you to order by something in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: No dice. Same error.

Comment: @Barmar it orders by other elements such as outlets. I'm wondering if it has something to do with aggregate data

Comment: I am able to UNION two aggregate SELECT in a very simple SQL. TOP 1 works but did not test with JOIN or WHERE or HAVING or ORDER BY clauses. Suggest you build the query in stages until it fails.

Comment: Ok then that can be ruled out. Will keep trying

Comment: @June7 the source queries are based on subqueries. Do you think it makes a difference?

Comment: Should work but since I don't know your data I can only say maybe.

Comment: But I can see it in the select area. I can only call it a bug

Comment: @June7 how do I use DESC on a field in SQL Access

Comment: Syntax you show is correct. If issue is with subquery, can't help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by including ORDER BY only in the first query and then removing all ending semicolons. Thanks for that bit @Uueerdo

Answer (score 0):

When using "TOP" and "ORDER BY" in the second SQL statement of a UNION query, I have experienced that it runs the TOP instruction first and then the "ORDER BY", so it makes no sense to order by anything here. With a simpler SQL example:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Ingresos.ID_Fra, Ingresos.Tipo, Ingresos.Numero, Ingresos.Fecha, "First Query" AS Tbl 
FROM Ingresos 
ORDER BY Ingresos.Fecha DESC
UNION
SELECT TOP 5 IngresosAnulados.ID_Fra, IngresosAnulados.Tipo, IngresosAnulados.Numero, IngresosAnulados.Fecha, "DEL" AS Tbl
FROM IngresosAnulados
ORDER BY Fecha DESC;
```

Source table: IngresosAnulados:

[image: Records on IngresosAnulados]

Assuming that the data in "IngresosAnulados" are these 10 records, the defined SQL statement shows the following result:

[image]

As you can see, it has taken five records from the second table and has ordered them by the field "Fecha", as specified, **but we do not know what the criteria are for having selected the five records that it has chosen**.

By the way, **it is necessary to indicate the name of a field selected in the first query** as the order of any of the union queries (except the first one). That's just what the error message says (The ORDER BY expression includes fields that are not selected by the query).

So **you will need two independent queries** (at least, an independent query for the second SQL statement) to get the record(s) that interests you in each of them and then join them in a UNION query if you really want the x top most of each UNION query to be displayed.